# Problem connecting to MySQL from NHibernate

Tags: .net, mysql, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 3.0 with MySQL as the database. On my localhost, I can connect to the database and do everything I want to. However, whenever I upload the files to the production server, I get an error which states:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

The web.config file has the following section:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration">    
<session-factory >
  <property name="connection.provider" specificversion="false">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class" specificversion="false">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
 <!--<property name="connection.connection_string" specificversion="false">
    Data Source=localhost;Port=3306;Database=sampledb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypass
    DSN=mydsn;UID=myuser;PWD==mypass
  </property>-->
  <property name="connection.connection_string">
    Server=localhost;Database=sampledb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass;
  </property>
  <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class" specificversion="false">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>      
  <property name="dialect" specificversion="false">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>      
  <property name="hbm2ddl.keywords" specificversion="false">none</property>
  <mapping assembly="App_Code.NHibernateHelpers" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have even tried the connection strings in the commented section shown above but nothing seems to work...yet all those work on my local machine. Can someone please tell me what I may be missing? My production server is a Windows 2003 server running .NET 2.x and MySQL connector 5.0.9.

Thanks.

Comment: I take it localhost can be resolved on your product server?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I even tried with the ip address and it did not connect. I have other asp.net sites on the same server (not running nhibernate) and have never had problems connecting to the database, be it MySQL or SQL Server. Don't know what is going wrong here!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your build session factory is using this web.config and there is not another configuration file kicking around anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the correct web.config is used. `SQL Server` as mentioned in you error is MS SqlServer and not mysql.

Have you forgot to add this to your web.config?

```
<configSections>
  <section name="hibernate-configuration"
  type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
</configSections>
```

Comment: I do have the correct web.config uploaded. The same works fine on my localhost. I have no idea why the error says SQL Server and not MySQL...but again, I never got this error on localhost. The portion you have mentioned is present in my web.config.